# Twisted UV (caracters to makes 15)

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, edit-mode, pose-mode

[image]
I dont know why the island is twisted it should be display as a rectangular in uv editor. I marked seam as in ss, the very top of my mesh then hit unwrap. And yes I already applied all transformations.

Comment: are you sure there are seams everywhere it's necessary to have a good unwrap? Maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I agree with moonboots. If you set your seams, where your creases are atm, it should unwrap decently, then you can start getting rid of superflouus seams.

Comment: moonboots and Frederik are correct I think. Is there only a seam around the top? And if so, is it completely around the top or is there one side missing? And did you unwrap with just the top faces selected or did you select the complete mesh?

Comment: Use Cube Projection to UV unwrap, no seams.